# how to use combobox in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, combobox

I want to have dropdown list which will have have values from database and for that I have following code in my view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpId, (SelectList)ViewBag.EmpId)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpId)
```

Now I want it such a way that is should contain values from database and it should also allow user to put manual entry if choice is not available in database.

and also do I need to use any java script plugin to have HTML helper for the same?

Comment: You can append a 'Other' option in the dropdown list along with list of options from db. If 'Other' is selected, show a `textbox to enter the custom option`.